# Overloading the ! (bang) operator

Tags: matlab, operator-overloading

In the answer to [this question](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101242-how-do-i-modify-the-system-command-or-bang-operator-in-matlab) the *MathWorks Support Team* states that:

> It is also possible to overload the ! (bang) operator by creating a
>   file called "!.m" and having this file be before the directory
>   $MATLABROOT\toolbox\matlab\general in the MATLAB search path.

I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I am running Matlab 9.1.0.441655 (R2016b) on Linux Mint. My path looks like that:

```
/home/raphael/Programs/Test
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/toolbox/matlab/iofun
...
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/toolbox/matlab/general
...
```

and I have created a file `!.m` in `/home/raphael/Programs/Test`. Whatever I put in this file the editor displays an error:

```
Line 1: Unable to run code analysis. '/home/raphael/Programs/Test/!.m' is an invalid file name.
```

As the ! (bang) operator is not listed in the [Operators and associated function list](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html), it is unclear what to put inside the `!.m` file.

I have nevertheless tried to put some code:

```
function bang(c)

disp(c)
```

but though `which !` returns my custom file path, Matlab invariably calls the built-in operator:

```
>> which !
/home/raphael/Programs/Test/!.m

>> !pwd
/home/raphael/Programs/Test
```

Renaming the file to `bang.m` resolves the error but has no effect on the bang operator.

So:

- Did Matlab's behavior changed since R2012?
- How could one overload the ! (bang) operator?
- And if this is actually possible, what should be the syntax of the function declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this undocumented handling of `!.m` disappeared in R2015b (presumably with the new execution engine changes that were also introduced with that release).

For versions earlier than R2015b, you can indeed name a file `!.m` on the path and then the name of the function *within* the file doesn't matter (as it never does in MATLAB).

**`!.m`**

```
function bang(varargin)
    disp('bang!')
end
```

In current versions of MATLAB, the `!` operator will ignore your `!.m` file but will call the underlying `system`, `unix`, or `dos` commands. Therefore you'll need to overload *those* commands instead.

So on OS X, overloading just `unix.m` does the trick:

**`unix.m`**

```
function varargout = unix(varargin)
    disp('My Unix Command')
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('unix', varargin{:});
end
```